# Style item of mat-expansion-descrption

Tags: html, css, sass, angular-material

I'm having trouble aligning my description "summary" or more specifically I want to have my item numbers in the panel header at the right end of the panel.

Here's what I already tried:

```
.mat-expansion-panel-header-description {
    flex-grow: 2;
    text-align: end; /*also tried "right"*/
}
```

and I also tried applying these properties to my summary class but nothing is working, they don't change their position like shown in my screenshot

```
.summary {
    text-align: right;
}
```

This is my html markup:

```
<mat-expansion-panel class ="mat-header" hideToggle *ngFor="let key of itemCategories">
    <mat-expansion-panel-header class="panel-header">
      <mat-panel-title>
        {{key}}
      </mat-panel-title>
      <mat-panel-description class="summary">
        <div *ngIf="items[key].length > 0">
          {{items[key].length}}
        </div>
      </mat-panel-description>
    </mat-expansion-panel-header>
    <div class="panel-content" *ngIf="items[key].length > 0">
      <ng-container *ngFor="let item of items[key]">
        <!-- Alle Bereiche -->
        <!-- <ng-container *ngIf="key == 'Alle Bereiche'">
          Alle Bereiche template
        </ng-container> -->
       <div>
        Name: {{item?.name}} <br> Betrag: {{item?.price}} <hr>
       </div>
      </ng-container>
    </div>
  </mat-expansion-panel>
```

This is what my app looks like with some explanatory marking

https://snipboard.io/f1aQMi.jpg

Without marking:

https://snipboard.io/f1aQMi.jpg

I can't figure it out and it's my first time working with Angular material, could someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong? Would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

It's tough to debug without a working example. `justify-content: space-between` allows you to separate elements in a flexbox, so perhaps you could utilise this:

```
.panel-header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

You can see more about that [here](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/j/justify-content/).

Here's an example of it in your use case:

```css
.panel {
  width: 20rem;
  height: 3rem;
  padding: 1rem;
  border: solid thin black;
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<div class="panel">
  <div class="title">Example title</div>
  <div class="value">10</div>
</div>
```